# create groups of groups for permissions

Tags: permissions, groups

Is it possible to add a group of groups to a SharePoint permissions group

Example:

Group A

- user1

Group B

- user2

Group C

- group A
- group B

Therefore, when I update A group C is inherently updated.  I can't do this in AD because this is a huge enterprise environment and this is for our internal site.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not permitted. You could add security groups into the Sharepoint groups if they exist though, distribution lists are not supported.

Answer (score 5):

You are out of luck. a SP group cannot contain any other SP group. It’s a big limitation.Although  SharePoint groups can contain (AD) users and AD groups.
Check this Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262690%28v=office.15%29.aspx

http://www.spdockit.com/blog/permissions-management-sharepoint-2013-part-two/

Answer (score 0):

Is this situation the same for SharePoint 2016 or 2019? I see value in managing users through a parent group and the group inheriting the permissions if users are managed in other groups (that inheritance could provide more restrictions)